# why do solids and pure liquids have no effect on yield and equilibrium?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, equilibrium, concentration

There are three parts to my question.

**Part one:**

- Let's assume we have a reversible reaction at equilibrium  as follows : Calcium carbonate (solid) goes into calcium oxide(solid) and carbon dioxide(gas).
- Let's assume that I add more calcium carbonate i.e I add more solid.
- Now I understand that there would be no shift in the position of the equilibrium since we added a solid therefore we induced a very negligible change in concentration ,  but what I am confused about is doesn't more reactant mean more product and doesn't more product symbolise a shift to the right?

**Part two:**

- I have read that the equilibrium constant $Kc$ and $Kp$ are really just close approximations of the true thermodynamic constant which uses activities hence the activity of a solid and pure liquid is always 1 .
- However upon further research I discovered that for an esterification reaction the equilibrium constant is 4 
  -First of all, the above reaction involves all pure liquids and hence the thermodynamic equilibrium constant would be one ,however why stick to a value of 4 why not easily say it is one since all activities are 1.

**Part three:**

- If we do take pure liquids in the $Kc$ value how do you measure the concentration of such a species, wouldn't the value be very high.My intution tells me that pure liquids are only taken when a reaction only involves pure liquids only , but they are not taken in heterogeneous reactions or when the liquid involved acts as a solvent as well.However in a case of a heterogeneous reaction only involving solids and liquids what will your equilibrium constant look like .

Lastly I have no knowledge of thermodynamics and I am still a high school student .

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5500/how-do-equilibrium-shifts-affect-solids?rq=1 https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14058/why-are-solids-and-liquids-not-included-in-the-equilibrium-constant-what-about?rq=1

Comment: If there are three parts of a question, than it is easier to tackle each of them as an individual question.  Otherwise, the question may be considered as *too broad* to be answered.

Comment: Regarding  your first part, although more reactant means more product,  the percentage yield is the same and thus, there is no shift in the position of equilibrium.